# Android currentThread.getStackTrace() Indexes

Tags: java, android, reflection, methods, stack-trace

I'm using the following to get the name of the method that called the currently executing method:

```
String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getMethodName();
```

Will the index (3) be the same across all Android devices? I saw in a few places that different JVMs have it arranged differently.

Comment: Are sure it is not `2`?

Comment: I'm positive. When I call it with `[2]` I get the name of the currently executing method (the method that called `String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[x].getMethodName();`)